# How would I combat this weird height bug for web pages on iOS devices? + Video not playing

Tags: html, css, iphone

I'm testing a demo site as of right now. I've set it up and it looks fine if I were to resize the browser, as it seems like the media queries I've set up are working properly. I noticed that on iPhone 5/5S/5C there would be some significant added height above the logo, as well as below it. I thought what would work to fix this is to add a negative margin to even out this strange space. Without the negative margin it looks like this on an iPhone 5/5S/5C:
[image: too much space]

On iPhone 6, 6+ this looks fine, as it should be. Also, on iPad it has the same strange spacing in between the logo.

With the negative margin that I added, when I would check the the site in developer tools and take it to the width of an iPhone 5 (320px), all the elements would be squished towards the top of the screen due to the negative margin like this:
[image: squished elements]

If you could look at my source code at the domain http://eugeneross.com/cw and tell me what I'm doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it, I've literally been pulling my hair out over this problem as to why it's not working on certain devices.

My other problem is that the video doesn't want to play now when the display is larger than a mobile screen. I must've messed something up trying to fiddle around with my problem above. If someone could tell me the problem there I would be ver grateful.

Let me know if you need anymore from my end to assist me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Deleted everything in

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {}
```

and it looks fine to me now.

[This is a good site](https://www.browserstack.com/responsive) where you can check how your site looks on all devices and some don't load the background cover.

Comment: It seems to work out for iPhone 5, but on iPad it still renders the same space gap issue.

Comment: do you mean the white space below the image? maybe try `background-size: 100% auto;` instead of cover

Comment: Sorry, no. I mean the space between the logo image, and the rest of the content.

Comment: It looks al fine here http://ipadpeek.com, i don't own a ipad so i can't test it unfortunately.

Comment: Right, it also renders and looks fine on the iPad device using Chrome tools, yet different on an actual iPad.